# Is the Czech president (negatively) known in other neighbouring countries?

Tags: president, public-opinion, czech-republic

In the Czech Republic lots of people don't like the Czech president [Milos Zeman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milo%C5%A1_Zeman) because of numerous cases in which he did things that seem to be very shameful.

I wonder if it's true that he is a disgrace for the Czech Republic in the eyes of the rest of the Europe? I assume that the probability of them knowing him is bigger in neighbouring countries (that is Germany, Austria, Poland and Slovakia).

Is he negatively known there? Is he known at all there? **Especially, I am curious about Germany.**

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, he's virtually unknown in the UK. As evidence, the most recent news story found on him searching the BBC news website is this one from 2014: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/world-europe-30087621/czech-president-pelted-with-eggs

Comment: @origimbo, Unfortunately, [The Gaurdian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/sep/14/milos-zeman-czech-leader-refugees) begs to differ.

Comment: @origimbo Cool thanks to both of you. (although after edit I made it does not technically answer to my question I am still curious in that)

Comment: To my best knowledge he is generally unknown in Poland.

Comment: From Germany: I remember reading some of his "muslim invader" comments on the refugee crisis. A google search on german google leads to a couple of recent news articles calling him "The Donald Trump of Czechia". So he isn't uknown, but the average man on the street will probably not know him if you were to do one of those street quizzes.

Comment: Do you even know the name of the German president? What about the Polish one?

Comment: @TGar, No, the Czech president is completely unknown here and I wouldn't have been able to say his name without looking him up. However the Hungarian president (or is it prime minister ?) Victor Orban is very mediatised and diabolized by the media here, basically they're saying this guy's super evil blah blah...

Comment: @JonathanReez I know something about them (and despite that I needed to google the names now, they weren't new names for me. I definitely heard of them and read some articles about both of them, also I knew the former Germany president name without looking it up). So I think it is possible, actually, I know e.g. Slovakian, Hungarian, Britain, France heads of state. It depends more on the concrete personality, and that is why I asked about this concrete men.

Comment: @Bregalad Thanks, and what is "here" in your case? Germany I expect?

Comment: @TGar Not Germany, but Switzerland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he probably has a fairly negative image overall in Germany. He is described as "pro-Russian", populist, or "immigration hardliner" sometimes in headlines, e.g.

- https://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2018-01/tschechien-milos-zeman-praesident-wahl-jiri-drahos
- https://www.welt.de/politik/ausland/article172920935/Tschechien-Migrations-Hardliner-Milos-Zeman-als-Praesident-wiedergewaehlt.html
- https://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/tschechien-milos-zeman-als-praesident-wiedergewaehlt-a-1190139.html
- https://www.dw.com/en/pro-russian-milos-zeman-wins-czech-republic-presidential-runoff/a-42333864

Even [passing mentions](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/tschechien-zehntausende-protestieren-gegen-justizministerin-marie-benesova-a-1268612.html) don't fail to tag him as "controversial".

And that's just the fairly recent coverage. Wikipedia has some ancient (2002) controversies in which he verbally attacked ethnic Germans, so that probably made an impression at the time, but I suspect few would remember after all this time.

So I suppose he is not well known, but those that have heard of him probably have a negative impression. I'm not sure what AfD etc. would think of him. Populist groups across Europe sometimes dig each other and sometimes hate each other...